How to repair this detached shower drain
So the shower was draining slowly due to clogging.  The first attempt at snaking it cause this separation at what seems to be a badly rusted mechanical joint.  What options do I have to repair this without removing the tiles and replacing the whole assembly?  Are there retrofit kits for this kind of problems?  There is a crawl space under the building.  I see a ABS P-trap under.  Also, I can't open the other screw for the cover I assume due to rust again.  any tips on that will be appreciated too!
Thank!





Since you have access from underneath in a crawl space, it should be repairable.
The bigger question to address is: What happened here? Did the drain pipe break or was it just not installed properly?
From the photo, it looks to me like the pipe was just not attached to the drain very securely, with only 2 or 3 threads engaged.
If the drain pipe is just sagging and flopping around in the crawl space then it might be an easy fix to re-attach. If the pipe is broken or settling under the building has pulled it loose, it might be a bigger problem.
EDIT:
I can't quite tell from the photo: I see some rusted threads in the green section I've marked, but are what I have marked in blue also threads or just the ribs of a push-fit adapter?

If it's just a push-fit and your aggressive snaking has pushed the pipe off of the coupling, then you might just need to go into the crawl-space and push the pipe back in place.

Hard to say; maybe both, but seeing the rusted threads in the middle, makes me think the drain assembly was broken off due to rust and 2-3 thread engaged as you said.  How do I re- attach (or attach new p-trap and abs pipe) back to this broken drain assembly full of rust and no threads?  Is there a smaller assembly that can sit inside this one?

If you can access it from the crawl space, it can be threaded on from the bottom.

Sorry but what can be threaded to what?  The current drain assembly is completely rusted and damaged with no threads left.

It looks like plenty of thread is left on the drain flange itself. You may need new plumbing pieces (adapters, pipe, elbows, etc.) under the drain, but the drain flange itself looks fine from the photo. But now that I look again, am I seeing threads on the bottom at all, or is it just a push-fit bushing? A good cleaning and another photo might help tell the story. Also a photo of the drain line from inside the crawl space would be helpful.

I see, but the one circled blue is not a thread I think.  it felt like a rubber like sleeve or something that is ribbed, not threaded.  I didn't know what it was until now that you mentioned push-fit bushing :)   as you cans the main thread is completely gone.

I can see that originally something was screwed to the drain assembly because you see part of the rusted broken piece around the separated pipe below (added a new photo).  I don't think the push-fit part can be a leak-free tight joint, do you?

A push-fit part would not be my first choice. Is this a repair that was done when the original, threaded part failed? Cleaning and more photos from within the crawlspace would be useful.

I don't think a repair was ever done at least not in the 7 years I've owned it.  I think it's just failed  now due to rust and snaking.  I'll try to go under this weekend and get a closet look...Thank you for the help so far!

Got pics from below?

no not yet, will try my scope first later...

I think i found the original part used there, It's "Oatey 2 in. 151 Cast Iron with 2 in. Sch. 40 No-Calk Connection" (https://www.amazon.com/Oatey-Cast-Iron-No-Calk-Connection/dp/B0069L06H6).  However they slipped an ABS 2" pipe there not cast iron.  Perhaps it was replaced later because I see an old iron p-trap down there. can this bushing hold a 2"  iron pipe but not ABS?
